# Do Papal Primacy and Consulates stack?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

[Papal Primacy](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Religion_%28Civ5%29#Founder_Beliefs): +15 to influence resting point with City-States following this religion
[Consulates](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Social_policies_%28Civ5%29#Patronage): +20 to influence resting point with all City-States

Assuming the city state has adopted the correct religion, is it possible to have a resting point that's permanently friendly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Yes.** Most things in Civ 5 stack as you'd expect them to. For instance, if you also pledged to protect the city state, your resting point would be +45.

The exception to this tends to be multiple bonuses which are the same e.g. the bonuses from two great generals wouldn't stack, the penalty from flanking can only occur once.